# How to get all contacts associated with a particular segment in mautic?

Tags: php, symfony, mautic

I want to list all the contacts associated with a particular segment in mautic but could not find any method for that. 
Here is my controller code

```
class DefaultController extends FormController
{ 

    public function listAction(){

        $model   = $this->getModel('lead.list');  


        $items   = $model->getEntities();  

        $listIds    = array_keys($items->getIterator());  

        $leadCounts = (!empty($listIds)) ? $model->getRepository()->getLeadCount($listIds) : []; 

        $parameters = array('items' => $items , 'leadCounts' => $leadCounts);  

           return $this->delegateView(
            array( 
                'viewParameters'  => $parameters,
                'contentTemplate' => 'MauticLeadPipelineBundle:Segments:index.html.php',
                'passthroughVars' => array(
                    'activeLink'    => 'tes_lead_pipelines',
                    'route'         => $this->generateUrl('test_lead_pipelines')
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

In view what I need is to show segment name with a list all the contact names associated with it.

```
 <?php foreach ($items as $key => $item) {?>
                <th>
                    <?php echo $item->getAlias();?>   


                </th>
                <?php }?>
```

I want a way so that I can fetch all the leads from that item object 
I have tried `$item->getLeads()` but that didn't work.

Comment: Lead id is present in `lead_lists_leads` table with respect to the segment, so try with that,